# How to add custom section to admin/auth/user/(x) page?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm not talking about just custom fields to the form or static data, I'm talking about adding a section which actually has it's own code. Kind of a new entry in the fieldset but which introduces not a new field but some small reports on the users's activity.

Actually this questions stands for any model's change page. The Django docs show you how to overwrite the template for this page but what good is that without adding some python code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overrride default templates and default views.

Django has two different views and templates for admin record displaying. One for creating a new one and one for displaying an existing one and editing it. Related methods are:

- [Add Form Template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_form_template) and [Add View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_view) for adding a new record
- [Change Form Template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_form_template) and [Change View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view) for displaying and changing an existing record

This is an example of how to prepare related override views (taken from [Add/Change View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view) link)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # A template for a very customized change view:
    change_form_template = 'admin/myapp/extras/openstreetmap_change_form.html'

    def get_osm_info(self):
        # ...
        pass

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['osm_data'] = self.get_osm_info()
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
            form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

You must check default django add and change templates from django source code (and maybe copying it as your new template and editing afterwards) to see how you can prepare your custom templates.

A final note, **Never** edit django template or vieew codes directly from source, since they are used by many different applications and and update to django source code might override your edit or may cause problems.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The Django admin is very extensible beyond overriding the templates.

Make sure you look at the [ModelAdmin methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods) section in the documentation.
You can modify pretty much any behavior of the ModelAdmin.

You should also look at the [custom form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/) and [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/) documentation, as a custom form for your model attached to its ModelAdmin gives you another (deeper, in most ways) level of customization.